# Running the huffman encoding algorithm on an empty file

Tags: huffman-code

This may be a stupid question, but compressing an empty file doesn't make any sense right?. The Huffman encoding algorithm on an empty file wouldn't work because it relies on the fact there have to be at least 2 nodes in the priority queue. If we run the algorithm on an empty file, the only node we would get is the one corresponding to EOF.

Answer (score 1):

Ya, that's right, it doesn't make much sense to run the Huffman encoding on it. Depending on the details of the implementation, it may not crash.

But why would you try to compress an empty file?

Comment: My homework is to create a file compressor based on huffman encoding. One of the test files provided by my teacher is an empty file.

Comment: Can't you just have a base case where if the file is empty, you just do nothing?

Comment: That's what I am thinking, but my TAs argue that an empty file should not be a problem. I don't know what they mean by that, but that's out of scope in this post. I just wanted to know your opinion,

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow encode at the start of the compressed data what symbols correspond to what Huffman codes. It is in that representation that the number of symbols would be indicated. If there is only one symbol, which has to be EOF per your description, then the Huffman coding is implied to be zero bits. If there is only one symbol, then you need zero bits to represent it.